# I want to play a sound in Java and it doesn`t work

Tags: java, audio

Hello I want to make an alarm clock and now I`m at the part at makeing the sound play....I wrote this

```
package audio;

import sun.audio.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
import sun.audio.AudioStream;



public class Audio {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        InputStream in;
        try{
        in = new FileInputStream(new File("‪sw.wav"));
        AudioStream audio = new AudioStream(in);
        AudioPlayer.player.start(audio);
        }
        catch(Exception e){}

}
}
```

And it doesn`t play the sound It doesnt give me an error it doesnt do nothing

I also put the direct pathway in a folder C:\...etc

Comment: well you are swallowing the exception.... maybe is your code failing but you dont notice that

Comment: It gives me a FileNotFound exception    - Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: ‪C:\Users\serban\Documents\wav sound\sw.wav (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

Comment: But the file path is correct...what is the problem ?

Comment: Is AudioStream an Android thing? I never used it in Java. Maybe you should have an Android tag on this post.

Answer (score 1):

try this: move the audio file to the source folder, then modify the path of the File in the form: `new File("‪./sw.wav")` and then do something helpful with the exception...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        InputStream in;
        try{
        in = new FileInputStream(new File("‪./sw.wav"));
        AudioStream audio = new AudioStream(in);
        AudioPlayer.player.start(audio);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            //print some helpfull info from the stack trace
        }
}
```

Comment: If the app and audio resource is ever packed into a jar, though, you'll need to use URL instead of File.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in defining the path of FileInputStream you should provide the full path of your audio file and seperate it with double slashes `\\`:

```
in = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\serban\\Documents\\wav sound\\sw.wav");
```

Or instead you can move the audio file to the source folder of your java program and then put:

```
in = new FileInputStream("sw.wav");
```